# MFC: how to make menu item auto-adjust to fit long string?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

When the caption of a menu item is long, part of it is cut off. Is there way to make it auto-adjust to fit the whole string?

```
POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "This is a pretty long me&nu item...\tCtrl+N", ID_FILE_LONG_ONE
```

Below is the screen shot (with some text concealed). What is seen in design doesn't match runtime; it doesn't display "Ctrl+N".

[image]

Comment: If your "main-frame" class (check `MainFrm.h`) contains a `CMFCMenuBar` member (which I guess it does) check the `CMFCMenuBar` public member variables and functions. A `CMFCMenuBar` is not a native window menu, instead it is derived from `CMFCToolBar`. Native menus are auto-adjusted to the menu max length. You may have to dig deeply into the MFC source to find this.

Comment: It might be worth actually showing a screen shot of the existing results and providing feedback in your question to the comments raised by @ConstantineGeorgiou.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, screen shot attached, I've seen the CMFCMenuBar member but not dig too deep yet.

Comment: Hi. I did a test with MFC and put a really long text string and whilst the editor displayed it right and run time it stripped the hotkey.  This was indeed with `CMFCMenuBar` as @ConstantineGeorgiou said.

Comment: What looks different in the design and run time pics is that the runtime one (which has the problem) uses one of the so-called "themes". I suspect some bug in the theme's code. This is easy to test, just create a new MFC application with the theme and another one with the "native" appearance (no themes). If there is indeed a bug, pick either another theme or  the native. Don't know what's so fascinating in making your app look like an old version of MS-Office, for example. Instead I find the "native" appearance not just acceptable, but even desirable. Otherwise, find the bug and fix it.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou, Yes, you are right. It works for native theme. I will also try the answer below since I need to implement accelerator for "Ctrl+..." anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, the menu items are adaptive and can automatically adjust the width based on the length of the string.

Regarding the problem of not displaying shortcut keys, In my opinion, you may not add shortcut key resources to the control.

For example:

1,Add a menu item with the ID "ID_FILE_Long". When you only modify the "Caption" in the properties. The results are shown in the following figure:

[image]

[image]

2,I suggest you should try to add shortcut key resources to the menu item.Open the Accelerator resource in the Resource view. And then add a shortcut for the menu item with the ID "ID_FILE_Long", as shown in the figure below:

[image]

3,The results are shown in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: Didn't seem to work on my test project. But then this is not my issue so I will let the original poster ask you about it if they have questions.

Comment: Neither for me, maybe because I am using VS 2008. I will switch to native theme as suggested by @ConstantineGeorgiou. Nevertheless I do appreciate your help!

Comment: Follow-up: it seems accelerator doesn't work well under my current theme vs native theme. Feel more convinced there is some bug for certain theme: (1) not showing correctly, and (2) not triggering correctly.